# React - Transform scale on hover messes with position absolute of sub component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, hover, css-transforms

I have an issue where I want to scale a `frame` on hover. When I do so a `sub` component, that have position absolute in the top right corner of the parent of `frame` pops in a out of the component that scales.

I want the component `sub` to stay in place at all times, however I can't really figure out how to do so.

[code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-burnell-6sdlp?file=/src/App.js)

I tried messing a bit with `transform-origin` but I can't figure out if that could solve my problem as is right now. I believe that something happens "behind the scenes" when I transform `frame`, but I can't figure out what it is.

## EDIT:

Thanks for the answers. However I assume I wasn't quite clear with what I wanted to achieve. I want the child to stay right where it is on the `frame` component (top right corner), so when `frame` scales up the `sub` still stays those (`15px`) outside of `frame`.

In the meantime I figured out what my problem is. As my `App` is a div `frame` increases the size of `App` as it scales up. As far as I remember `div` parents usually scale to the same size as their child components, and this seems to be the issue here.

It became clear to me when I put a border on `App`. So with that in mind it might be a better solution to put `position: relative` on `frame` and just position `sub` negatively on `top` and `right`.

Yet again, thanks for the answers. They helped me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your position relative from .App to .frame class

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.frame {
  position: relative; // move position relative here
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this configuration when `sub` is a child of `frame` just make sure to give a `frame` `position: relative;` in styles

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="frame">
    <div className="sub">Hello, World!</div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

```
.frame {
  position: relative;     // add position relative
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `position:relative`, as soon as the frame transforms, the `sub` tries to realign it self with your given `top` and `right` properties... same will occur with `position:absolute` because it also takes the parent for reference..

so we have to move `sub` out of `frame` and use `position:absolute` to get what you're looking for...

relevant **JavaScript**:

```
<div className="frame" /> 
<div className="sub">Hello, World!</div>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.sub {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

[forked & updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wave-sr343?file=/src/styles.css:353-361)